# Python regex, how to delete all matches from a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of regex patterns.

```
rgx_list = ['pattern_1', 'pattern_2', 'pattern_3']
```

And I am using a function to loop through the list, compile the regex's, and apply a `findall` to grab the matched terms and then I would like a way of deleting said terms from the text.

```
def clean_text(rgx_list, text):
    matches = []
    for r in rgx_list:
        rgx = re.compile(r)
        found_matches = re.findall(rgx, text)
        matches.append(found_matches)
```

I want to do something like `text.delete(matches)` so that all of the matches will be deleted from the text and then I can return the *cleansed* text.

Does anyone know how to do this? My current code will only work for one match of each pattern, but the text may have more than **one** occurence of the same pattern and I would like to eliminate all matches.

Comment: Do you need those matches at all? Maybe it is easier to just `re.sub` the text first thing? Also, the order of patterns matters. You should see to that beforehand.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `sub` to replace matched patterns with an empty string. No need to separately find the matches first.

```
def clean_text(rgx_list, text):
    new_text = text
    for rgx_match in rgx_list:
        new_text = re.sub(rgx_match, '', new_text)
    return new_text
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple regex you can OR the expressions together using a "|". There are examples of combining regex using OR on stack overflow.

For really complex regex I would loop through the list of regex. You could get timeouts from combined complex regex.

Comment: Could you share some example or link?