# How to use regex to delete a specific section of text after a regex match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

(No, [Python regex, how to delete all matches from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192606/python-regex-how-to-delete-all-matches-from-a-string) doesn't solve my problem)

Suppose I have this list:

```
names = ['your name', 'the name', 'his name', 'her name', 'their name', 'employer name', "employer's name", "father's name",
        "mother's name", "maiden name", "son's name", "daughter's name", "brother's name", "sister's name"]
```

And suppose I have this piece of text:

```
text = "What is your name?  Well,  uh it's John Smith.  Thanks for asking. Anyway, I'd doing well."
```

How do I use regex to find every element of the list names in the text, and replace the block of text (say, of length 50) immediately after the element with " [name] ".  So my output would be:

```
text = "What is your name [name] Anyway, I'd doing well."
```

So far, I have this code below, but it only replaces the element with " [name] " not the actual text after the element.

```
def my_replace3(match):
    match = match.group()
    return " [name] "

def no_name(text):
    names = ['your name', 'the name', 'his name', 'her name', 'their name', 'employer name', "employer's name", "father's name",
        "mother's name", "maiden name", "son's name", "daughter's name", "brother's name", "sister's name"]
    regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(names) + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(regex, my_replace3, text)
    return text
```

I'm not a great regex expert, so your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh...gee, why is there a downvote?  Did I do something wrong?  I tried looking for a solution already on stackoverflow but couldn't find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex, how to delete all matches from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192606/python-regex-how-to-delete-all-matches-from-a-string)

Comment: Use `regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(names) + r')\b.{0,50}', re.I | re.S)` and then `text = re.sub(regex, '[name] ', text)`, see https://ideone.com/hyQxfM

Comment: @SudharsanaRajasekaran He doesn't want to delete the matches from the string, he wants to delete the text *after* the matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace 50 characters after the match, add `.{50}` to the regexp.

Then use a back-reference in the replacement string to copy the matched string to the replacement.

```
def no_name(text):
    names = ['your name', 'the name', 'his name', 'her name', 'their name', 'employer name', "employer's name", "father's name",
        "mother's name", "maiden name", "son's name", "daughter's name", "brother's name", "sister's name"]
    regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, names)) + r')\b.{50}', re.IGNORECASE)
    text = re.sub(regex, r'\1 [name]', text)
    return text
```

You should also use `re.escape()` when inserting strings that should be matched exactly into the regexp, in case any of them contain regexp operators.

Comment: `re.escape` in the context of the `\b` word boundary and OP's `names` is not so important. If there are special chars at the start/end of the search words, it will not be enough to use `re.escape`.

Comment: `{0,50}` means anything up to 50, `{50}` means exactly 50. If there can be less than 50 characters after the match, you should use `{0,50}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point, but in this case it's probably just special characters in the middle that would be a problem.